Cannot get second and third parameter from MVC View
I have View where I have a button to download the document
 @foreach(var document in Model.Documents)
        {
            <tr data-id="@document.Id" data-file-id="@document.FileId" data-file-name="@document.Name">
                <td><a class="btn btn-info" asp-action="DownloadDocument" asp-route-vehicleServiceId="@document.VehicleServiceId" asp-route-fileId="@document.FileId" asp-route-fileName="@document.Name">@L("Download")</a></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@document.Name"/>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="@document.Description" /></td>
                <td class="delete-button-column"><button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete">@L("Delete")</button></td>
            </tr>
        }

here is a script in View
<script id="documentTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
<tr data-id="{{id}}" data-file-id="{{fileId}}">
    <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="@(Url.Action("DownloadDocument") + Html.Encode("?vehicleServiceId={{vehicleServiceId}}&fileId={{fileId}}&fileName={{name}}"))">Download</a></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{name}}" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{description}}" /></td>
    <td class="delete-button-column"><button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
</tr>

In Controller I have this method
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadDocument(int vehicleServiceId, Guid fileId, string fileName)
        {
            var file = await AttachmentHelper.GetFromAzureBlobAsync($"{vehicleServiceId}/{fileId}", AppConsts.VehicleServiceDocumentsContainerName);
            return File(file.Content, "application/octet-stream", fileName + ".pdf");
        }

The problem is that when I click the button I have only vehicleServiceId parameter.  fileId and fileName are empty.
If I delete vehicleServiceId={{vehicleServiceId}}& part, I get fileId, etc.
What I'm doing wrong?

I tried to use it this way and it solved my problem
    <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="@(Url.Action("DownloadDocument") + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("?vehicleServiceId={{vehicleServiceId}}&fileId={{fileId}}&fileName={{name}}"))">Download</a></td>


So you used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode instead of Html.Encode ? is Html.Encode a valid method?  just wondering why you want to decode it instead of encode? ...
